# Query to find duplicates by an OR condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-partitioning

I'm working on a query to eliminate duplicates from my table.  I need to use this condition to identify duplicates:

```
(user_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id AND born_on matches) OR (first_name, last_name, and born_on matches)
```

Among these duplicates, I need to retain the records with the earliest creation date, meaning I don't want my query to include the duplicate with the earliest date. In short, my query should only return duplicate records while excluding the one with the earliest creation date.

I tried something like this but I don't think we can partition by conditions:

```
WITH RankedDuplicates AS (
  SELECT
  first_name,
  last_name,
  born_on,
  user_id,
  assigned_to,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY
    (user_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id, born_on) OR
    (first_name, last_name, born_on)
    ORDER BY assigned_to
  ) AS row_num
  FROM my_users
)

SELECT
first_name,
last_name,
user_id,
ssn,
assigned_to
FROM RankedDuplicates
WHERE row_num > 1;
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get this query to work?

```
CREATE TABLE my_users (
    id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    born_on date,
    user_id integer,
    assigned_to date
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_users_pkey ON my_users(id int4_ops);

INSERT INTO public.my_users (first_name, last_name, born_on, user_id, assigned_to) VALUES
(NULL, NULL, '2011-01-01'::date, 23433, '2023-06-01'::date),--This record would not be returned because it is the earliest matching Mike Smith.
('Michael', 'Smith', '2011-01-01'::date, 23433, '2023-08-01'::date),
('Mike', 'Smith', '2011-01-01'::date, NULL, '2023-07-01'::date),
('Foo', 'bar', '1988-07-03'::date, 13434, '2023-03-01'::date),
('Foo', 'Bar', '1988-07-03'::date, NULL, '2023-08-01'::date), --This record would not be returned because it is the earliest matching Foo Bar.
(NULL, NULL, '1988-07-03'::date, 13434, '2023-05-01'::date),--This record would not be returned because no matching record
('John', 'Doe', '2000-03-08'::date, 23433, '2023-09-01'::date),--This record would not be returned because no matching record
(NULL, NULL, '1988-07-03'::date, NULL, '2023-05-01'::date);--This record would not be returned because no matching record
```

Comment: You have tagged both mysql and postgresql. Which one are you really using? The answer could be different depending on which brand you are using.

Comment: Tag spamming is highly frowned upon here. MySQL and PostgreSQL are two entirely different products, with different functionality and syntax. It's highly unlikely that you're using both simultaneously with the code above, which means it's also highly likely that one of those tags does not apply to your post. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and should be used properly.

Comment: I'm using Postgres. I removed the mysql tag. I was under the impression that it would apply to both.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
WITH RankedDuplicates AS (
  SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    user_id,
    born_on,
    assigned_to,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
      CASE
        WHEN user_id IS NOT NULL THEN user_id::text
        ELSE first_name || last_name
      END, born_on
      ORDER BY assigned_to DESC
    ) AS row_num
  FROM my_users
)

SELECT
  first_name,
  last_name,
  user_id,
  born_on,
  assigned_to
FROM RankedDuplicates
WHERE row_num > 1;
```

Comment: This actually does not return all the duplicates because we need to do an OR. For example, perhaps the user_id is not null but has a different user_id. I still want to match by first_name, last_name, and born_on.

Comment: Can you give me the intended result from your example table?

Comment: I added a comment on the insert statements Thanks.